# How to create has_many association with "includes" and "where" conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here is the situation: a store has many products, and can join multiple alliances. But the store owner may not want to display certain products in some alliances. For example, a store selling computers and mobile phones might want to display only phones in a "Phone Marts".

By default, all products in the store will be displayed in all alliances one shop joins. So I think building a product-alliance blacklist (I know it's a bad name...any ideas?) might be a convenient way.

The question is: how to create a "has_many" to reflect such relations like the behaviours of function `shown_alliances` and `shown_products`?

I need this because `Car.includes(:shop, :alliances)` is needed elsewhere, using functions make that impossible.

Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :alliances, -> { uniq }, through: :store
  has_many :blacklists

  def shown_alliances
   alliances.where.not(id: blacklists.pluck(:alliance_id))
  end
end
```

Store:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :alliance_store_relationships
  has_many :alliances, through: :alliance_store_relationships

  has_many :allied_products, -> { uniq }, through: :alliances, source: :products
end
```

Alliance:

```
class Alliance < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alliance_store_relationships
  has_many :store, through: :alliance_store_relationships
  has_many :products, -> { uniq }, through: :companies
  has_many :blacklists

  def shown_produtcts
    @produtcts ||= produtcts.where.not(id: blacklists.pluck(:produtct_id))
  end
end
```

Blacklist:

```
class Blacklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :produtct
  belongs_to :alliance
  validates :produtct_id, presence: true,
                     uniqueness: { scope: :alliance_id }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :shown_alliances, ->(product) { where.not(id: product.blacklists.pluck(:alliance_id) }, class_name: 'Alliance', through: :store, source: :alliances
  # ...
end

class Alliance < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :shown_products, ->(alliance) { where.not(id: alliance.blacklists.pluck(:product_id) }, class_name: 'Product', through: :companies, source: :products
  # ...
end
```

You can specify a condition for associations. See [docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Customizing+the+query)

Comment: Thank you Jay-Ar! I wrote `has_many :alliances, ->(alliance) { includes(:blacklists).where.not(alliance.id: blacklists.pluck(:alliance_id)) }, through: :shop, source: :alliances` but not working.
 seems I'm just not familiar with this "where" usage.

Comment: your `...where.not(alliance.id: blacklists...`, should be `...where.not(id: product.blacklists...`, can you also try removing the `source: :alliances` part? as I think that should already be implied by default. And also use `->(product)` and not `->(alliance)`

Comment: If it didn't work, I think you'll need to specify `source`. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Oh your alliance is connected to product through :companies. I've updated my answer. Ensure that your `Company` model has_many :products

Comment: Yes your answer is just what I want. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! :) Feel free to mark this answer correct so that the question will already be closed.

Comment: One more thing, I've had an `allied_products` relation: `has_many :allied_products, -> { uniq }, through: :alliances, source: :products
`. But now I get `undefined method `blacklists' for Company` error. How can I change the code to make it correct? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `has_many :allied_products, -> { distinct }, through: :alliances, source: :products` instead? `uniq` enforces an Array which might cause the error.

Comment: Not working either. The problem is ActiveRecord tries to call Compay.blacklists, which does not exist.

Comment: hmm that's strange. I'm not sure why its calling blacklists for Company. I'll have to reproduce this first.

Comment: Hey, @Jay-Ar Polidario have you got any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I was a little busy lately and intentionally skipped trying to reproduce this problem. I might also still need to see the Company model of yours, so that'd be handy if you could update your question as well. If you could however, replicate this project of yours into a stripped-down version and send me the zipped file, that would be better because I can immediately reproduce the problem you were having, although I cannot guarantee if I could solve it, but I will try.